# The uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^J$ is finer than the product topology and coarser than the box topology

Tags: general-topology

In Munkres *Topology* (page 124, Ch: Metric Topology) he states the following theorem:

> The uniform topology on $\mathbb{R}^J$ is finer than the product topology and coarser than the box topology; these three topologies are all different if $J$ is infinite.

By the statement of the theorem, it seems Munkres is referring to the finer and coarser comparisons as those of the finite product/box topology. However, earlier in the text he states that for a finite product space the box and product topology are the same!

So should not the uniform topology either be finer than both the product topology and box topology or coarser for both the product/box topology?

Thanks!

Note:

Uniform metric definition for an $n$ coordinate product space:

$$\bar{p}(x,y) = \sup\left\{\bar{d}(x_i - y_i), i \in n \right\}. $$

Comment: "Finer" and "coarser" are not *strict* conditions.  If $J$ is finite, then the product topology is both finer and coarser than the box topology (implying that they are the same).  The uniform topology fits between the two, though the distinction only matters when $J$ is infinite.

Comment: ah shoot! i now remember thinking this when first reading over the theorem! so to be clear, Munkres could have written the theorem switching finer and coarser and it would still hold true, correct? (in the finite case)

Comment: In the finite case, they are all the same, hence I suppose that one *could* reverse the language, but that would be rather silly, as the theorem is only interesting in the infinite case, where the relation is as stated.

Comment: @XanderHenderson However, the author explicitly states that if $J$ is infinite, these three topologies are different!

Comment: @onurcanbektas Yes, and?  Isn't that exactly what I said?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I thought _different_ means "not comparable", I don't know why I have thought like that, but anyway :) Thanks by the way.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, if product and box are same for finite case how can uniform sit between the two? Munkres ends the theorem saying that ‘Showing these three topologies are different if $J$ is infinite is left to the exercises’. If infinite case is left to the exercise, isn’t he talking about the finite case in the proof?

Comment: @danny In the finite case, all three topologies coincide.  The uniform topology sits between the box and product topologies in the same way that $\frac{2}{2}$ sits between $0.\overline{9}$ and $1$.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, thanks. But which case is Munkres proving in the theorem finite or infinite? Is index set $J$ necessarily  infinite? Also I get confused since he takes $U_\alpha$ to be $R$ except for finitely many. Can we do this within finite case itself or does this imply Munkres is dealing with the infinite case. If so why he leaves infinite case to the exercise?

Comment: For *any* $J$ it is true that $(\text{product topology}) \subseteq (\text{uniform topology}) \subseteq (\text{box topology})$.  This is *always* true.  However, if $J$ is finite, all three topologies coincide (the reverse containments can be demonstrated).  It is only in the infinite case that anything interesting happens, i.e. the topologies are *not* the same.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\mathcal T_p$, $\mathcal T_b$, and $\mathcal T_u$ be the product, box, and uniform topologies on $\mathbb R^J$, respectively.

For any $J$, it is the case that $\mathcal T_p\subseteq\mathcal T_u\subseteq\mathcal T_b$.

However, if $J$ is finite, then $\mathcal T_p=\mathcal T_b$, which implies that $\mathcal T_p=\mathcal T_u=\mathcal T_b$.

Comment: However, the author explicitly states that if $J$ is **infinite**, these three topologies are different!